# If vectors are linear independence they span the space?

Tags: linear-algebra

is it possible to assume 
span just because the vectors are
Linear independence?
or in other words any set of n vectors
 that are linear independence span Rn?

Comment: Not if $n<3$, no.

Comment: What about two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: sorry my mistake,I wanted to write Rn no R3

Comment: fewer than $n$ vectors will not span $\mathbb R^n$, even if they are linearly independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Counter-example: $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are linearly independent but do not span $\Bbb R^3$, only the plane $z=0$.

The correct fact is: if $V$ is a vector space with $\dim V = n$, and $S \subseteq V$ is a set with $n$ elements, then the following are equivalent:

1. $S$ is linearly independent;
2. $S$ spans $V$;
3. $S$ is a basis for $V$.

The crucial assumption is that $S$ has *exactly* $n$ elements.

Comment: I believe instead the example should instead say they span $y=0$?

Comment: Is the vector $(0,1,0)$ in the plane $y=0$?

Comment: I changed the vector (0, 0, 1) to (0, 1, 0) to make the statement about z = 0 correct

Comment: So paulinho was not wrong originally - see the edit history

Comment: The statement was just edited by Vincent, see above.

Comment: Oh, I think I saw the comment after the edit. Alright, thank you all for pointing it out